# In Ruby, why does mutability mean that the interpreter cannot use the same object to represent two identical string literals?

Tags: ruby, string

Strings are mutable in Ruby. This means that - unlike in Java - the interpreter cannot use the same object to represent string literals (i.e. `"test"` in a for loop will create a new object for each iteration).

Can someone explain to me why this is the case? i.e. why does mutability prevent using the same object to represent string literals?

Comment: Imagine `"test".upcase! == "test"` returning `true` – that would be pretty confusing.

Comment: Good point! Thanks. That was a perfect one-line answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
two_foo = 2.times.map { "foo" }
two_foo[0] << "bar"
two_foo
# => ["foobar", "foo"]
```

If the `"foo"` was only allocated once, and then reused, the result would be `["foobar", "foobar"]` instead, which would violate the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). If someone really wants to do that, the same object should explicitly be used:

```
foo = "foo"
two_foo = 2.times.map { foo }
two_foo[0] << "bar"
two_foo
# => ["foobar", "foobar"]
```

Comment: Why would the result *necessarily* be that?  Isn't the change being made to `two_foo`, not the string itself?

Comment: `String#<<` mutates the string; unlike `two_foo[0] += "bar"`, it does not touch the array at all. See the second example for an explicit demonstration of what happens when the reference is shared.